# What is &+/2 in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Saw this in elixir guide:

`Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], 0, &+/2)`

What the heck is &+/2 ? I can't seem to google it for the life of me.

Comment: More about function capturing: https://elixir-examples.github.io/examples/function-capture

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this example you capture the module function `+/2`. Capture operator `&` turns module function into anonymous one. Here it captures the `+/2`, which is actually `Kernel.+/2`. Read more [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#+/2).

Comment: The answer from PatNowak is absolutely correct, but the first sentence can cause confusion if you are a newcomer to Elixir. It would be less confusing this way: "In this example you capture the arithmetical addition function +/2 from the Kernel module" instead of just "In this example you capture the module function +/2".

Comment: I was confused about this as well being a newcomer. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a basic idea

For Ex: `&(&1 + 1)` --> is same as:   `fn x -> x + 1 end`

Here `(&1)` is considered as "First argument"

In your case of `&+/2` is similar to :   `fn a,b -> a+b end`

`&+/2` can be also written as, `&( &1 + &2 )`, both were the same , Here`&2` is second argument

If we want to access `&+/2` this function, (let's assign the function to a variable), i.e; `add = &+/2`

`add.(1,2)`

Output : 3